# Vectorized element assignment involving comparisons between matrices in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I'm currently trying to replace the for-loops in this code chunk with vectorized operations in Numpy:

```
def classifysignal(samplemat, binedges, nbinmat, nodatacode):
    ndata, nsignals = np.shape(samplemat)
    classifiedmat = np.zeros(shape=(ndata, nsignals))
    ncounts = 0
    for i in range(ndata):
        for j in range(nsignals):
            classifiedmat[i,j] = nbinmat[j]
            for e in range(nbinmat[j]):
                if samplemat[i,j] == nodatacode:
                    classifiedmat[i,j] == nodatacode
                    break
                elif samplemat[i,j] <= binedges[j, e]:
                    classifiedmat[i,j] = e
                    ncounts += 1
                    break
    ncounts = float(ncounts/nsignals)
    return classifiedmat, ncounts
```

However, I'm having a little trouble conceptualizing how to replace the third for loop (i.e. the one beginning with `for e in range(nbinmat[j])`, since it entails comparing individual elements of two separate matrices before assigning a value, with the indices of these elements (i and e) being completely decoupled from each other. Is there a simple way to do this using whole-array operations, or would sticking with for-loops be best?

PS: My first Stackoverflow question, so if anything's unclear/more details are needed, please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Why did you put the first "if" statement inside for loop over range(nbinmat[j]) ? I see nothing depends on e inside it? Besides, shouldn't "classifiedmat[i,j] == nodatacode" be "classifiedmat[i,j] = nodatacode"?

Comment: The problem is really in the elif clause, like you say. Perhaps this code could not be fully rewritten (some parts can though), but maybe the "bigger picture" can? If you could shed some light on what it is you actually want to do (where does `binedges`come from, why do you need to compare every single element of an array to elements in a possibly staggered array), then perhaps more help is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some concrete examples and explanation it's hard (or at least work) to figure out what you are trying to do, especially in the inner loop.  So let's tackle a few pieces and try to simplify them

```
In [59]: C=np.zeros((3,4),int)
In [60]: N=np.arange(4)
In [61]: C[:]=N
In [62]: C
Out[62]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

means that `classifiedmat[i,j] = nbinmat[j]` can be moved out of the loops

```
classifiedmat = np.zeros(samplemat.shape)
classifiedmat[:] = nbinmat
```

and

```
In [63]: S=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [64]: C[S>8]=99
In [65]: C
Out[65]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0, 99, 99, 99]])
```

suggests that

```
if samplemat[i,j] == nodatacode:
   classifiedmat[i,j] == nodatacode
```

could be replaced with

```
classifiedmat[samplemat==nodatacode] = nodatacode
```

I haven't worked out whether loop and break modifies this replacement or not.

a possible model for inner loop is:

```
In [83]: B=np.array((np.arange(4),np.arange(2,6))).T
In [84]: for e in range(2):
    C[S<=B[:,e]]=e
   ....:     
In [85]: C
Out[85]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0, 99, 99, 99]])
```

You could also compare all values of S and B with:

```
In [86]: S[:,:,None]<=B[None,:,:]
Out[86]: 
array([[[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

The fact that you are iterating over:

```
for e in range(nbinmat[j]):
```

may throw out all these equivalences.  I'm not going try to figure out its significance.  But maybe I've given you some ideas.

Comment: thanks for the help! it most definitely has given me some ideas to work with.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you want to use vector operations you need to solve the problem using linear algebra. I can't rethink the problem for you, but the general approach I would take is something like:

- res = Subtract samplemat from binedges
- res = Normalize values in res to 0 and 1 (use clip?). i.e if > 0, then 1 else 0.
- ncount = sum ( res )
- classifiedMat = res * binedges

And so on.